# checking zero size file

Tags: file, size, zero

I am writing a batch file to run every day on windows server.
and check if the size of specific file in specific folder is zero, then send me an email. I found %~z1 which check size of file is zero, but I do not know where should I put %~z1 and filename in my ifcommand. I do not want to use loop, because it is just checking one single file per day.

### Here is what I did:

@echo off 
set out="C:\foldername\test1.txt"

if "%out%" == "0" ( 
    sending email ( I know this part )
    ) else ( 
    echo do nothing

### )

Please advise!
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

This should get you what you need

```
For %%i in ("C:\path\to\file.ext") do set var=%%~zi
echo %var%
```